# MYSQL sum of item purchases and its 'up'/'down' votes are multiplied by a factor of 22?

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum

I'm trying to count the number of purchases and 'up'/'down' votes for all items that match a given search term. Unfortunately, as I've set up my query now, the purchases and vote counts are multiplied by a mysterious factor of 22 that I can not figure out where it comes from.

As an example for one of the items: the purchases, up, and down votes should be 7, 2, and 1 respectively but they are instead 154, 44, and 22.

here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT *
sum(purchaseyesno) as tots,
sum(rating=1) as yes,
sum(rating=0) as no
from items
join items_purchased
on items_purchased.item_id=items.item_id
join accounts 
on items.account_id=accounts.account_id 
like subject='%album by joe%' or description='%album by joe%'
group by item_id
order by tots desc, yes desc
```

Here's some sample data:

```
subject        tots   yes   no   full_name 
album by joe    154    44   22    joe smith
album by fred   88     44   0    fred jones
```

Here's how i'd like the data to look:

```
subject        tots   yes   no   full_name 
album by joe    7      2    1    joe smith
album by fred   4      2    0    fred jones
```

Would someone be able to help me figure out what is going on here? I can't figure out this factor of 22 issue which persists despite changing the `group by` and other things (meaning, this 22 number is independent of the # of returned rows).

Comment: Tim,Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: hi Vutukuri, i updated my question with some sample data and desired output, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your schema but it might help to use a subquery:

```
SELECT subject, tots, yes, no, fullnane
  FROM (
    SELECT item_id, SUM(purchaseyesno) AS tots, SUM(rating=1) AS yes, SUM(rating=0) AS no
    FROM items_purchased
    GROUP BY item_id
  ) i
  JOIN items ON i.item_id = items.item_id
  JOIN accounts ON items.account_id=accounts.account_id 
  WHERE subject LIKE '%album by joe%' OR description LIKE '%album by joe%'
  ORDER BY tots DESC, yes DESC
```

Comment: Hi Neil, yes a subquery is exactly what i needed, problem solved! I just couldnt' figure out how to do that but your solution is perfect. For future reference, can you point out an example from stackoverflow on someone showing their schema well? thanks!

Comment: @timpeterson well, I think most people just include some sample rows from the original tables (in a similar format to your results).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subject,
sum(purchaseyesno)/22 as tots,
sum(CASE WHEN rating=1 THEN 1 END)/22 as yes,
sum(CASE WHEN rating=0 THEN 1 END)/22 as no,
full_name
from items
join items_purchased
on items_purchased.item_id=items.item_id
join accounts 
on items.account_id=accounts.account_id 
like subject='%album by joe%' or description='%album by joe%'
group by subject,full_name
order by tots desc, yes desc
```

In this query,the SUM function basically works on the columns purchaseyesno,rating=1,rating=0.

For eg.

```
Subject purchaseyesno rating full_name 
1       5             1      Mark
1       6             0      Mark
2       7             1      Robert
2       8             0      Robert
```

The above query will return as below.

```
Subject tots yes no full_name 
1       11   1   1  Mark
2       15   1   1  Robert
```

Comment: I don't know from which tables your columns are coming from.You can just add those alias infront of your column names.

Comment: You do not solve the problem, only gave an acceptable solution.

Comment: Hi Vutukuri, this does work but I'm still confused as why the counts are being multiplied inappropriately. Can you help me understand how the sum() function works? Even if I simplify the join statements, the sums are still being multiplied inappropriately. ugh!

Comment: The sum function basically works on a column based on the columns in your group by clause.I will post in detail about sum function in the above answer.

Comment: thanks Vutukuri, the answer from Neil about using a subquery is what worked for me. thank you though for your input,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't do `select *` if you're grouping by. Remember you must group by all non-aggregated fields.

Secondly, the high amount of results must be comming from those joins. Remove the group by and the aggregated columns and inspect the results and you'll see why you're getting so many records.

Finally... you're missing a `where` clause there...

Comment: hi Mosty, thank you. I'm not sure how to use a where clause since this is a search query and one would want all the results that are `like` the search term but not necessarily match it exactly (`where'). I got rid of the select * and group by statements but this led to even higher number of results. oh man, this stinks.